# Simple getter setter

Tags: apex, visualforce, getter, setter

How to pass value from user side or vf page side by using this type of getter setter is there any way to pass value using this type?

Here is the Code

```
public class simplegetset
{
    public String userinput{
        get{
            return userinput;
        }
        set{
            this.userinput = userinput;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="simplegetset">
  <!--<apex:form>
    <apex:outputlabel value="Enter your name here"/>
       <apex:inputtext value="{!userinput}"/>          
  </apex:form>    -->

  <apex:form >
    <apex:outputlabel value="Enter your name here"/>
       <apex:inputtext value="{!userinput}">
           <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" rerender="display" />
       </apex:inputtext><br/>                   
    <apex:outputpanel id="display">
        <apex:outputtext value=<b>"The name entered is = {!userinput}" </b> />
    </apex:outputpanel>                   
  </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally hunted down a deep dive into how properties work that you should read top to bottom: [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) from the `Apex Developer Guide`.

---

If you want to declare a setter, you must set the property equal to the incoming `value`.

```
public String userInput
{
    get { return userInput; }
    set { userInput = value; }
}
```

You can also use the simplified form here since you are not doing anything more fancy:

```
public String userInput { get; set; }
```

The problem with your code as posted was that you set `userInput` to itself, so it is always `null`.

---

[@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) has astutely pointed you towards [Building a Custom Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) from the `Visualforce Developer Guide`, but I think his own explanation is actually a better read for you here: [Apex Controllers: What do the get; set; do?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71700/apex-controllers-what-do-the-get-set-do)

---

There's also a useful link from Summer 08 on the `Salesforce Developers Blog` called [Property Accessors in Apex in Summer ’08](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html).

> Basically, instead of writing the following in a class:
>
> ```
> String prop;
> public String getProp() { return prop; }
> public void setProp (String p) { prop = p; }
> ```
>
> we can now write this:
>
> ```
> public String prop {get; set;}
> ```
>
> Many keystrokes saved. Note that the latter doesn’t actually generate a `getProp()` method, see below.
>
> **Syntax examples**
>
> That’s actually an abbreviated abbreviated syntax. The get and set can be expanded somewhat to contain custom code. For example:
>
> ```
> public String prop { get {return prop;} set {prop = value;} }
> ```
>
> A couple of things to note here:
>
> - The `get` body must end in a return, sensibly…
> - The `set` body receives an implicit argument called `value` of the same data type as the property.
>
> You can also omit a get or a set, in which case the property becomes write or read only, respectively.