# I'm getting an error "Unknown property 'PDSrestCall.userProfile.ibmUniqueId'"

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout

I'm trying to display my deserialized JSON on my VF page but I get Unknown property 'PDSrestCall.userProfile.ibmUniqueId' Help Please.

PS i removed the API endpoint for security purposes.

Here is my code:

```
global with sharing class PDSrestCall {

    public String requestMethod {get;set;}
    public String requestEndpoint {get;set;}
    public String responseStatus {get;set;}
    public Integer responseStatusCode {get;set;}
    public String responseBody {get;set;}
    public List<userProfile> userDetails {get;set;} 



    global static void restCall() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

       HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

       userProfile u = (userProfile)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),userProfile.class);

       system.debug('ibmUniqueId: ' + u.ibmUniqueId);
       system.debug('ibmId: ' + u.ibmId);
       system.debug('userName: ' + u.userName);
       system.debug('firstName: ' + u.firstName);
       system.debug('lastName: ' + u.lastName);
       system.debug('email: ' + u.email);
       system.debug('phone: ' + u.phone);
    }

   public List<SelectOption> getMethodOptions(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('GET','GET'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('POST','GET'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('PUT','GET'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('DELETE','GET'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('HEAD','GET'));
        return options;
    }


    global class userProfile{
        public String ibmUniqueId;
        public String ibmId;
        public String userName;
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String email;
        public String phone;


        public userProfile(String ibmUniqueId, String ibmId, String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone) {
            this.ibmUniqueId = ibmUniqueId;
            this.ibmId = ibmId;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
            this.phone = phone;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my VF code:

```
<apex:page id="page" controller="PDSrestCall" >
    <apex:form id="form" >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="RESTFUL Callout Viewer" />
        <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessages" />
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Callout and Deserialize" action="{!restCall}" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline!='1'}"/>
            <!--       <apex:commandButton value="Deserialize" action="{!getDeserializeProfileDataService}" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline!='1'}"/> -->

                <apex:commandButton value="Callout and Deserialize  (offline)" action="{!restCall}" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline=='1'}" />
            <!--     <apex:commandButton value="Deserialize (offline)" action="{!getDeserializeProfileDataService}" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline=='1'}" /> -->

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="HttpRequest" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="setMethod()" />
                <!--    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!requestMethod}" > 
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MethodOptions}" />
                    </apex:selectList>  -->
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                 <!--   <apex:outputLabel value="setEndpoint()" />
                    <apex:inputText value="{!setEndpoint}" style="width:90%" /> -->
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="HttpResponse" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="getStatusCode()" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!responseStatusCode}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="getStatus()" />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!responseStatus}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="getBody()" />

                    {!responseBody}
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="JSON Deserializer"  collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!userDetails}" var="i" >
                    <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Owner" style="width:100px;" >
                        <apex:outputLink value="{!i.owner.link}" target="_blank" style="width:100px;" >
                            <apex:image value="{!i.owner.profile_image}" alt="{!i.owner.display_name}" style="height:30%; width:30%;" /><br/>{!i.owner.display_name}
                        </apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column> -->
                    <apex:column headerValue="ibmUniqueId" style="width:75px;" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.ibmUniqueId}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ibmId" style="width:75px;" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.ibmId}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="userName" style="width:75px;" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.userName}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="firstName" style="width:75px;" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.firstName}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="lastName" style="width:50px;" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.lastName}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="email" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i.email}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice how your controller has attributes annotated with getters and setters:

```
public String requestMethod {get;set;}
```

You need to do the same for your class definition. Note that you should use `private` setters unless you actually want the page to sat an attribute, and you should not use getters or setters for variables you do not need to reference on your page.

```
global class userProfile{
    public String ibmUniqueId { get; private set; }
    public String ibmId { get; private set; }
    // and so on
}
```

See also:

- [Simple getter setter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/142572/2995)
- [Apex Controllers: What do the get; set; do?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/71700/2995)
- [Property Accessors in Apex in Summer ’08](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html)