# get picklist values from Prod

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, getpicklistvalues

Hello guys I have been working with a LWC form at the dev environment and I made a LWC form that gets the picklist values from an specific object with the default recordTypeId 012000000000000AAA. In the dev environment all the picklist values appears in the form but when I made the deployment to the prod environment the picklist values does not appear.

My js code:

```
import defaultRecortTypeIdLabel from '@salesforce/label/c.QX_DefualtRecordTypeId'; 
import Field1 from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c.Fiel1__c';
```

in this import I bring the defaultRecordTypeId of the object. Then I used the getPicklistValues

```
item1;
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: defaultRecortTypeIdLabel, fieldApiName: Field1 })
    wiredPicklistItem1({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.item1 =  data.values;
        }else if(error){
            console.log('Error in values: '+ JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }
```

But I am not getting the values. Does the prod environment has a different recordTypeId? Could anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should never hardcode id's in your code or flows as id's will be different accros environments.
You can either work with custom metadata or custom labels to store part of such configuration but for recordtype IDs you are better off retrieving them through [a property as described in this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71700/apex-controllers-what-do-the-get-set-do)

```
public *var type* someName {
    get {
        // this block equals to: 
        //     public *var type* getSomeName()

        // work with someName     
        return someName; 
    }
    set {
        // this block equals to: 
        //     public void setSomeName(*var type* value)

        // work with value
        someName = value;
    }
}
```

recordtype ID's themselves can be retrieved through following SOQL

```
SELECT ID, developerName 
FROM Recordtype 
WHERE DeveloperName= :recordtypeName AND SObjectType = :objectType
```

Comment: Hello I do not want to use a SOQL because I have lots of picklist to use. Is there an alternative?

Comment: 012000000000000AAA is a rare exception to the "hard-coded ID" rule. This is the "null ID" for record types, which represents the "--Master--" record type.